# Is there way to make the Eclipse WTP JSP editor treat the body of a custom TagLib as JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsp, eclipse-wtp

I've written a simple taglib (called `Script`) that takes its body's content, wraps it in an HTML `<script>` element and inserts it at the bottom of an outer taglib (called `Body`). This is to automate the initialization of [Zurb's Foundation 4](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html).  This means this JSP:

```
<r:page>
  <r:head title='Test Site'/>
  <r:body>
    <div id='thing'></div>
    <r:script>
      $(function() {
        $('#thing').html('DOM is ready');
      });
    </r:script>
  </r:body>
</r:page>
```

Is rendered as this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]><html class='no-js lt-ie9' lang='en'><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class='no-js' lang='en'><!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8' />
    <title>Test Site</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/foundation.min.css'>
    <script src='/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js'></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src='http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js'></script><![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='thing'></div>
    <script>
      document.write('<script src=/js/vendor/' + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery') + '.js><\/script>')
    </script>
    <script src='/js/foundation.min.js'></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
      //The contents of the <r:script> from the JSP
      $(function() {
        $('#thing').html('DOM is ready');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now the downside to this approach is that the Eclipse WTP JSP Editor sees the body contents of the script taglib as just more HTML, so I lose JavaScript syntax highlighting.  Is there some way (possibly by adding information to the `.tld` file or creating a `TagInfo` Class to tell the JSP editor that the body is mean to be read a JavaScript? or is the only approach to just add a `<script></script>` element by hand (and for clarity sake rename the custom taglib something like `onFoundationReady`).  Also just in case it's still possible to to convince smarter people than myself that this extra effort is worth it in the first place, the alternative would be to include the boilerplate Zepto/jQuery loader and `$(document).foundation();` at the bottom of each page, and when include the fact that I'm also using Facebook Connect via the JavaScript SDK there is a lot of boiler plate code that this taglib is cleanly hiding from me)

Comment: Also to the potential question "Why not just use a regular `<script>` element for this, because jQuery or Zepto are loaded at the bottom, any attempt to use the on dom ready shortcut (`$(function() {});`) would cause a `$ is undefined` error if it appeared inside the `<r:body>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.  There's nothing in the JSP specification that conveys any relevant information about the body content of the tag that the editor can use beyond processing it like the rest of the page or treating it as "hands off."

Changes could be made to WTP that *might* allow *another* Eclipse plug-in to determine syntax coloring for that region, but I really don't know if that one specific feature is something worth the effort involved.

Comment: Sigh... well knowing that it is not possible is better than not knowing at all and searching in vain